# Web Service gets unavailable after several concurrent calls

Tags: performance

We are testing GoDaddy Virtual Data Center and came to a very strange issue when our web site gets unavailable. GoDaddy Support keeps saying the issue is in our web server settings, but looking at the result of our tests I doubt it.

TEST ENVIRONMENT

- Virtual DataCenter with Windows hosted at GoDaddy.com. All servers have Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, IIS 7.
- Server One with IP address 10.1.0.4
- Server Two with IP address 10.1.0.3
- Both servers are in private network not visible from outside.
- Port Forward with IP address 50.62.13.174. Port Forward is assigned to Server One

TEST DESCRIPTION

- JMeter is used as a Client App to simulate 30 concurrent users sending 100 SOAP requests each. Interval between requests is 1 second.
- Http link used for testing: http://50.62.13.174/v2/webservices.asmx

TEST ONE

- Test is run from a computer in our office.
- After JMeter starts running test, almost immediately, the link above becomes unavailable in a browser.
- After test completion, the link is not available in a browser for about 5 more minutes.
- Remote Desktop is working well, so we can connect to Server One remotely.
- After about 5 minutes since test completion, the link becomes available in a browser again.

TEST TWO

- Test is run from Server Two (that is part of our virtual data center).
- Test works very well, no visible delays in processing.
- The link is available in a browser all the time.

TEST THREE

- Test is run from Server One using localhost.
- The result is the same as in TEST TWO - no issues.

TEST FOUR

We repeated TEST ONE from other computers that we have located in different countries, all with the same result as TEST ONE.

CONCLUSION

As the test works well from Server Two, but does not work from outside our virtual data center, we feel there are issues with the network or its capacity.
The whole behaviour looks like out requests from outside get stuck somewhere before reaching our virtual data center.

Has anybody had similar issues in the past? Are there chances that something is wrong with our server settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it's DDOS protection, as all traffic come through same ip during jmeter test.

Do a wireshark trace on server One to see if your ip is still reaching server when broken. Even with iis stopped, you must see incoming tcp request to the web server port

Comment: I guess in this case the link would not be available from the client machine only, but it gets unavailable from other client machines too. Thanks for wireshark advise, will check it.

Comment: @roman it's the public ip that get blocked, so i agree if you tested from others internet access

Comment: Also check event log for Application pool crash, just in case of

Comment: @ Mathieu Chateau: do you mean that ip 50.62.13.174 gets blocked? By whom, our Internet Provider?

Comment: As you tested from different place on the world, your ISP is not guilty for me. So Godaddy may be blocking your internet public ip from where your launch jmeter

Comment: Actually, we found the issue. By mistake, we out 10 ms connection timeout in JMeter. As soon as we changed it to 10 s, the tests worked well.